# Как одним запросом вывести id если от даты регистрации прошло 3 дня

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня есть регистрация и мне надо отправить людям зарегистрировавшимся 3 дня назад письмо.

Как сделать это в запросе?

код:

```
SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE ((NOW() - data_reg) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)) and type_staff = '1'
```

Comment: А у вас поле date или datetime, т.е. есть ли там время. И если время есть, то что такое "3 дня назад" надо с часами определиться

Comment: @Mike, у меня в UNIX вот так 1478366242, мне надо отправить всем у кого регистрация равна или превышает например 3 дня.

Comment: Ну превышает 3 дня просто `date_reg <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY` но туда попадут и пользователи которые зареганы год назад ... вас это устроит или вам например нужны сутки между 3 и 4 днями

Comment: @Mike а как учесть именно этот год?

Comment: Этот год или год с текущей даты. т.е. c 1 января или с 15 ноября прошлого года ? начало текущего года `concat(year(now()),'0101')` а если год с текущего момента то  `date_reg between now()-interval 1 year AND now()-interval 3 day`

Comment: @Mike дает ошибку date_reg between now()-interval 1 year AND now()-interval 3 day

Comment: Какую ошибку ? только что проверил, скопировав ваш текст - работает отлично

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48519/discussion-between-alexander-sizintsev-and-mike).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужны сутки между 3 и 4 дня назад, то как-то так:

```
SELECT id
FROM staff
WHERE data_reg BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

С различными типами хранения возможны свои нюансы, но суть такая.

**Edit**: из комментариев стало понятно, что для даты-времени используется тип int. Тогда запрос может выглядеть так:

```
SELECT id
FROM staff
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(data_reg) BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `staff` WHERE data_reg BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL $time_to_day+1 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL $time_to_day DAY)"); ничего вообще не выводит

Comment: (1) А есть записи удовлетворяющие этому условию? (2) Какой тип у поля data_reg?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev было бы замечательно, если бы вы привели пример из нескольких записей. Лучше сразу на sqlfiddle.com чтобы можно было дать рабочий запрос.

Comment: даже этот запрос не выполняется SQL запросе в phpMyAdmin =|  может какие-то проблемы из за того что date_reg хранится как int(20)?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev А в самом вопросе нельзя было сразу сказать что у вас дата в int ... Потому как дату принято хранить в datetime. В общем вам надо переводить все интервалы `unix_timestamp()`

Comment: @Mike дико извиняюсь. не подумал сразу... и как это сделать?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Ну все о чем мы говорили, только `unix_timestamp(NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY)`

Comment: @mike все сделал спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev дополнил ответ вариантом для int

Comment: @artoodetoo я так и сделал. спасибо.